# Implementing IEqualityComparer modifies equality test results?

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

I implemented a `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>` for `MyObject` in order for my priority queue to be able to sort elements (the use does not really import here, but whatever).
Thus, I implemented the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

My question is: when I do `MyObject1 == MyObject2`, does it use the tests written by me in the `Equals` method or is it a classical equality test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is a reference type, `==` will only perform any custom operations if you overload the == operator:

```
public static bool operator ==(MyClass1 x, MyClass1 y)
{
    ...
}

public static bool operator !=(MyClass1 x, MyClass1 y)
{
    ...
}
```

The C# compiler doesn't know about any relationship between the `Equals` method and the `==` operator, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Agh, you beat me to it by five seconds. Upvote will have to suffice.

Comment: That answers exactly my question. Simple. Thanks